# Add a link field to block form

Tags: 8, forms, blocks

I've created a module with a custom block that extends `BlockBase`. To the block form I added multiple textfields and select boxes, by simply specifying the formatter in the `'#type'` configuration.

My next step is to add a button that links to internal/external content and I've tried adding different types, such as 'link' but without any luck.

I found [LinkFormatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!link!src!Plugin!Field!FieldFormatter!LinkFormatter.php/class/LinkFormatter/8), but I can't figure out how to use it properly with block forms.

What has to be added to the blockForm method in order to create a link field (just like the `link` field that's selectable within a custom block type):
[image: UI showing available link options]
[image: Field options for link]

My current code:

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  //...
  $form['link'] = [
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => $this->t('Link title'),
    '#url' => 'Hmm?',
    '#options' => ['external' => TRUE]
  ];

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: The code has nothing to do with the screenshot. The code tries to output an "<a href..." html tag. The screenshot contains two text inputs to enter a link. The first text input has a database lookup. If you want this input and no output, you have to define these inputs in code, where do they come from and how to submit them.

Comment: I changed some details in the question. What I want is the "Link" field that's available on custom block types.

Comment: The code you are looking for is here:
core/modules/link/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/LinkWidget.php

Comment: I posted a solution for a related question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213472/add-link-field-in-custom-form-drupal-8/272914#272914

Answer (score 0):

You want to change `'#type' => 'link'` to `'#type' => 'url'`

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  //...
  $form['link'] = [
    '#type' => 'url',
    '#title' => $this->t('Link title'),
    '#options' => ['external' => TRUE]
  ];

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: This will only result in a `<input type="url">` and not the desired result shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code:

```
$form['group1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => $this->t('Link Field'),
  '#collapsible' => FALSE,
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,  
);

$form['group1']['url'] = array(
  '#type' => 'url',
  '#title' => $this->t('URL'),
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'node',
);

$form['group1']['label'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('Link Text'),
);
```