# Add link field in custom form

Tags: forms, 8

I want add link field (label + url internal/external) in custom form

This not work:

```
$form['test_ink'] = array(
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => $this->t('Link title'),
  '#url' => '',
);
```

Answer (score 16):

The `link` ([Link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Link.php/class/Link/8.2.x)) render element type is used to *render* an anchor element on a page, and not used to provide an input element in a form that is constrained for URLs.

As an example you may look at [LinkWidget::formElement](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!link!src!Plugin!Field!FieldWidget!LinkWidget.php/function/LinkWidget%3A%3AformElement/8.2.x), which shows how that field widget creates form elements for a Link field. And the way it does this is to use the `url` ([Url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x)) form element, which will provide an input element that validates URLs. Make sure that the `#url` property is a valid ([Url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromRoute/8.7.x)) object.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Url;

$form['test_link'] = [
  '#type' => 'url',
  '#title' => $this->t('Link title'),
  // Example of a Url object from a route. See the documentation
  // for more methods that may help generate a Url object.
  '#url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 1]),
];
```

**Edit**:

1. Added @imclean's suggestion to the answer for readability

Comment: Note that for internal links the `url` type is *not* used, rather the `entity_autocomplete`.

Comment: Note that you can also use the linkit element if you have the linkit module (see https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit):
$form['test_ink'] = [
        '#type' => 'linkit',
        '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'linkit.autocomplete',
        '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => [
          'linkit_profile_id' => 'default',
        ],
      ]

Comment: Make sure the URL is a URL object or it simply won't work.  For example:


`use Drupal\Core\Url;

$element['test_link'] = [
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => t('Link title'),
  '#url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.node_type.collection'),
];`

Answer (score 6):

I liked @mpp's answer on how to create a linkit field if you have Linkit module enabled.
His example was not code formatted, so this is just a repost using formatted code for better readability and to make it easier to copy paste this to use in your own projects. Create a linkit field with Drupal's form api:

```
$form['block_link'] = [
  '#type' => 'linkit',
  '#title' => $this->t('Select link target'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Start typing to see a list of results. Click to select.'),
  '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'linkit.autocomplete',
  '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => [
    'linkit_profile_id' => 'default',
  ],
  '#default_value' => isset($config['block_link']) ? $config['block_link'] : '',
];
```

Note that you can change 'default' to any linkit profile you might have in your project.
Also note: my default value in this case comes from a block config form because I added this linkit field to a block's settings page. Remove #default_value if it is not applicable to your case or change it depending on where you get your value from.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling across this post looking at adding Linkit to a config form (thanks @mpp and @Flyke), there's been a slight change in the API: `'linkit_profile_id' => 'default',` should now be `'linkit_profile' => 'default',`

```
 $form['block_link'] = [
  '#type' => 'linkit',
  '#title' => $this->t('Select link target'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Start typing to see a list of results. Click to select.'),
  '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'linkit.autocomplete',
  '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => [
    'linkit_profile' => 'default',
  ],
  '#default_value' => isset($config['block_link']) ? $config['block_link'] : '',
];
```

Small point but worth knowing.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem when I needed to add a link (url+label) to the theme settings form. I didn't use the *url* field cause it has a bug if the user wants to add an internal link.

This is how it looked on the CMS:

[image]

This is the code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter().
 **/
function francisco_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id = NULL) {
  // Work-around for a core bug affecting admin themes. See issue #943212.
  if (isset($form_id)) {
    return;
  }

  $form['francisco_theme_option_sidebar'] = array(
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => t('Sidebar'),
    '#description' => t('Lorem ipsum.'),
    '#open' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['francisco_theme_option_sidebar']['francisco_theme_option_sidebar_footer_cta_title'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('Link Title'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('francisco_theme_option_sidebar_footer_cta_title'),
    '#description'   => t("Lorem ipsum."),
    '#maxlength' => 255
  );

  $form['francisco_theme_option_sidebar']['francisco_theme_option_sidebar_footer_cta_url'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('URL'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('francisco_theme_option_sidebar_footer_cta_url'),
    '#description'   => t("Lorem ipsum."),
    '#maxlength' => 2048,
  );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**To add link field (label + url internal/external) & core link widget's url field validation in custom form:**

```
$form['resource_fieldset']['design_tool_link'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'node',
  '#title' => $this->t('Design Tool Link'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Select Design Tool Link'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#element_validate' => [
    [
      'Drupal\link\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\LinkWidget',
      'validateUriElement',
    ],
  ],
  '#attributes' => [
    'data-autocomplete-first-character-blacklist' => '/#?',
  ],
  '#process_default_value' => FALSE,
  '#default_value' => $design_tool_link ?? : '',
];

 $form['resource_fieldset']['title'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('Title'),
];
```

**Note: by adding #element_validate attribute :**

- Custom Url field 'll accept external & internal links as default core
  link widget's URL field do
- Also validation of core link 'll applied instead of writing same
  validation again